# 301 redirect isn't working for special characters

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have added a 301 redirect but it seems to be not working

```
Redirect 301 example.com/?1 https://www.example.com/
Redirect 301 example.com/!@#$124 https://www.example.com/
```

I want to redirect all example.com/specialcharacters to https://www.example.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `mod_rewrite` rules for this. Place this rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} . [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/\W
RewriteRule ^ /? [L,R=302]
```

`\W` matches all non-word characters so second condition will trigger if there any non-word character at start of `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: it's not redirecting the site.

Comment: Sorry had a typo, try it now. Also **verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not**, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: Yes it's enabled but the updated code is also not redirecting.

Comment: Ah! It worked when I moved the script to the top. Thanks mate.

Comment: I tested with these characters the redirect isn't working example.com/#$ however for other characters redirect is working.

Comment: Yes this redirect rule must be topmost rule. Also if `#` is first rule after `example.com/` then web server can't do anything because browser won't send any part starting with `#` to web servers.